# How can I prevent NaN from appearing when printing?

Tags: java, class, methods, printing, numbers

This is my task.

1. Write a class named Stock that contains:

   - A String data field named symbol for the stock symbol.
   - A String data field named name for the stock’s name.
   - A double data field named perviousClosingPrice that stores the stock price for the previous day.
   - A double data field named currentPrice that stores the stock price for the current time.
   - A constructor that creates a stock with the specified symbol and name.
   - A method named getChangePercent() that returns the percentange changed from previousClosingPrice to currentPrice.
2. Write a StockTest class that creates a Stock object with the stock symbol ORCL, the name Oracle Corporation, and the previous closing price of 34.5. Set a new current price to 34.35, and display the price – change percentage.

and

my code is this

```
public class Stock{
  private String Symbol, Name;
  private double previousClosingPrice, currentPrice;
  public Stock(String stockName, String stockSymbol){
    Name = stockName;
    Symbol = stockSymbol;
  }
  public double getChangePercent(){
    return (previousClosingPrice - currentPrice)/previousClosingPrice * 100;
  }
}

 import java.util.Scanner;
public class StockTest{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String stockSymbol = "ORCL";
    String stockName = "Oracle Corporation";
    double previousClosingPrice = 34.5;
    double currentPrice = 34.35;
    Stock stock = new Stock(stockName, stockSymbol);
    double percentChange = stock.getChangePercent();
    System.out.println("The company" + stockName + "has a stock price of" + currentPrice +".");
    System.out.println("Which is an increase of " + stock.getChangePercent() + " % increase");
  }
}
```

and I just get this output:

```
The companyOracle Corporationhas a stock price of34.35.
Which is an increase of NaN% increase
```

I want to show an actual number and not NaN

Comment: `double previousClosingPrice = 34.5;` you should not be using this, your should use the `Stock` variables.  You will need a method to set these fields

Comment: I'm still a newbie so can you elaborate on that please I don't fully understand this

Comment: `NaN` is a pseudo-number (not a number). It indicates that you made a math error somewhere, perhaps dividing by zero.

Comment: In `getChangePercent` you are dividing by `previousClosingPrice` but this value has never been set.

Comment: Meaning that it was initialized to `0.0` as the default value.

Comment: Your code has two different variables named `previousClosingPrice` – one of them has a value assigned (34.5), the other one does not. The one that does _not_ have a value assigned ends up with the default value for a `double` data type, which is `0.0`. When you are printing things, your code is using the variable with value `0.0` and not `34.5`. This is happening with the other variable as well – `currentPrice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `double previousClosingPrice = 34.5;` in your main method, that's creating a variable that is entirely separate from the field named `previousClosingPrice` in your stock class. Yes, they have the same name. This doesn't make them magically the same thing.

You should not have that line at all, in your main method.

As written there is no way for your main method to adjust the previousClosingPrice field in any given stock instance; the field is private, and there is no method that can change it. I suggest you make a method named `public void setPreviousClosingPrice(double value) {this.previousClosingPrice = value;}`.